# Generate USDZ Thumbnail on server, not device

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, realitykit

I'm aware that you can generate USDZ thumbnails with AR Quick Look with Swift on iOS and iPadOS. Is there a way I can do that on an Ubuntu machine (i.e. a server) rather than a physical mobile device? I want a way to store PNG/JPEG/Image thumbnails.

Comment: I was reading today that you can install the Apple USDZ tool kit on Linux, but I am not sure if it has any exporting tools to anything other than USDZ. I've used headless Blender sessions to make tricky thumbnails in the past, that could work, it doesn't take too long to spin up. I'm wanting to do the AR Quick Look thing and am searching for how to do that currently.

Comment: Since I'm supporting both iOS and Android, I've instead started using the glb equivalent files and Shopify's screenshot CLI toolkit: https://github.com/Shopify/screenshot-glb